# Symfony - StreamedResponse works but request.CRITICAL error in the log

Tags: symfony, symfony5, sylius, symfony6

Here is the controller method I have implemented :

```php
public function download(
        string $id,
        ChannelRepository $channelRepository,
        CustomerNewsletterRepository $customerNewsletterRepository
    ): Response
    {
        $channel = $channelRepository->find($id);
        $customerNewsletters = $customerNewsletterRepository->findAllIterable($channel);

        set_time_limit(3600);
        ob_flush();

        $response = new StreamedResponse();
        $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
        $disposition = HeaderUtils::makeDisposition(
            HeaderUtils::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            'export.csv'
        );
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);
        $response->setCallback(function () use ($customerNewsletters): void {
            $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($fp, ['Email', 'Date'], ';');
            /** @var CustomerNewsletter $customerNewsletter */
            foreach ($customerNewsletters as $customerNewsletter) {
                fputcsv($fp, [
                    $customerNewsletter->getEmail(),
                    $customerNewsletter->getCreatedAt()->format('d/m/y H:i'),
                ], ';');
                flush();
            }
            fclose($fp);
        });

        return $response->send();
    }
```

It works as expected. When I click on the download button, I can get a file

But, in the `dev.log` I can see a critical error :

```bash
grep "CRITI" dev.log

[2023-07-07T11:35:23.192510+00:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "The content cannot be set on a StreamedResponse instance." at website/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/StreamedResponse.php line 124 {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): The content cannot be set on a StreamedResponse instance. at website/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/StreamedResponse.php:124)"} []
```

How to avoid this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with Sylius, and it was due to a plugin I have installed.

Here is the issue on Github : https://github.com/spinbits/sylius-google-analytics-plugin/issues/33